# Best practice for loading multiple dynamic services and them dependencies services

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, microservices

I want to devlop a custom system for my self.

I want to loading custom services by configuratin with dependency services - for example:

```
<Services>
    <Service name="ServiceA" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceA" dependencies=""/>
    <Service name="ServiceB" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceB" dependencies="ServiceA"/>
    <Service name="ServiceC" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceC" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB"/>
    <Service name="ServiceD" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceD" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB,ServiceC"/>
    <Service name="ServiceE" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceE" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB,ServiceC,ServiceD"/>
    <Service name="ServiceF" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceF" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB,ServiceC,ServiceD,ServiceE"/>
</Services>
```

All those services are implement custom interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
    bool IsReady {get;}
}
```

What the best practice for loading dynamic services toghether but depends on those dependencies?

Loop every service and postpone till those dependencies are loaded and ready?

Have any tutorial for that?

Comment: This is a [Dependency Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph)..

Comment: it's also topological sort? good idea!

Comment: Yes, topology sort solutions will give you the correct loading order.

Comment: "Loop every service and postpone till dependencies are loaded" risks an infinite loop if for instance you have a cycle in the dependencies.

Comment: if the dependencies are not loaded successfully so i dont want to load the service..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The best approach is using Graphs to map the dependencies for a given service. I've just put an example using Dependency Injection framework because them already do that. Feel free to use it, or create your own.

Using any Dependency Injection tool (Unity, Simple Injector, Autofac, Structure Map, Ninject) will inject the dependencies directly. Here's an example using Unity:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
container.RegisterType<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
```

When you ask for ServiceB instance, it will inject ServiceA on it:

```
var serviceB = container.Resolve<IServiceB>();
```

More info about Unity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: thanks, but it's not my question how to inject a services, my question is what is the best practice for loading services but with the promise that the dependency services are loaded before the service is loaded..

Comment: just put more info into my answer. If you want to do it by yourself, here's a sample: http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.co.nz/2009/09/creating-your-own-ioc-container-part-2.html

Answer (score 0):

After i getting a suggesting from Mr. Remus Rusanu.

My solution is:

Here is the interface for the topological sort:

```
public interface ITopologicalSort
    {
        string Id { get; }
        IList<ITopologicalSort> Dependencies { get; set; }
    }
```

The topological sort:

```
public static Dictionary<int, IList<T>> TopologicalSort<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getDependenciesFunc) where T : class, ITopologicalSort
        {
            var groups = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var sortedGroups = new Dictionary<int, IList<T>>();
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                TopologicalSortInternal(item, getDependenciesFunc, sortedGroups, groups);
            }
            return sortedGroups;
        }

 private static int TopologicalSortInternal<T>(T item, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getDependenciesFunc, Dictionary<int, IList<T>> sortedGroups, Dictionary<string, int> groups) where T : class, ITopologicalSort
        {
            int level;
            if (!groups.TryGetValue(item.Id, out level))
            {
                groups[item.Id] = level = INPROCESS;
                var dependencies = getDependenciesFunc(item);
                if (dependencies != null && dependencies.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var dependency in dependencies)
                    {
                        var depLevel = TopologicalSortInternal(dependency, getDependenciesFunc, sortedGroups, groups);
                        level = Math.Max(level, depLevel);
                    }
                }
                groups[item.Id] = ++level;
                IList<T> values;
                if (!sortedGroups.TryGetValue(level, out values))
                {
                    values = new List<T>();
                    sortedGroups.Add(level, values);
                }
                values.Add(item);
            }
            return level;
        }
```

What the code is doing?
He is sorted by dependencies.

So for this example:

```
<Services>
    <Service name="ServiceA" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceA" dependencies=""/>
    <Service name="ServiceB1" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceB1" dependencies="ServiceA"/>
    <Service name="ServiceB2" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceB2" dependencies="ServiceA"/>
    <Service name="ServiceC1" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceC1" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB1"/>
    <Service name="ServiceC2" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceC2" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB2"/>
    <Service name="ServiceD" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceD" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB2,ServiceC2"/>
    <Service name="ServiceE" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceE" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB2,ServiceC2,ServiceD"/>
    <Service name="ServiceF" args="" type="CommonLib.IServiceF" dependencies="ServiceA,ServiceB1,ServiceC1,ServiceD,ServiceE"/>
</Services>

Level 0: ServiceA
Level 1: ServiceB1, ServiceB2
Level 2: ServiceC2, ServiceC2
Level 3: ServiceD
Level 4: ServiceE
Level 5: ServiceF
```